# Is ther a dragOver event if ag-grid-react?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to use ag-grid-react to implements something similar to a file manager where the user  can drag&drop rows (ie rows) on to folders (ie other rows) (but not on to other files).

Is there a dragOver event in ag-grid-react where I can decide if a row is a valid drop target?

NB: I know that I can do this decision onDrageEnd. But I want to show the user where dropping makes sense.